# Undefined local variable or method `user' - how do I reference user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render a list of users in a html.erb page but getting the error that the user variable is undefined.

As I understand, for the view to adopt the @users variable it needs to be called in a controller that is linked to the route of the view. I've tried this below but I think I'm calling the controller wrong (and thus the index method that defines @users). How would I go about fixing this so that the partial will render with the list of users?

**views/pages/contacts.html.erb:**

```
<table class='table table-condensed'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render 'contact', collection: @users, as: :user %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**views/pages/_contact.html.erb:**

```
<%= content_tag :tr, id: dom_id(user) do %>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to 'Add Contact', [:new, :contactship, id: user], remote: true unless current_user.has_contactship?(user) %>
      <%# or link_to 'Add Contact', new_contactship_path(id: user), remote: true %>
      <%= link_to 'Accept Request', [:contactships, id: user], method: :post, remote: true if current_user.requested_contacts_with?(user) %>
      <%= link_to 'Remove Request', [:contactship, id: user], method: :delete, remote: true if current_user.pending_contacts_with?(user) %>
      <%= link_to 'Remove Friend', [:contactship, id: user], method: :delete, remote: true if current_user.contacts_with?(user) %>
    </td>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  resources :contactships, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  devise_for :users
  authenticated :user do
    root "pages#my_circles", as: :authenticated_root
    get "/app/views/pages/to_post.html.erb", to: "pages#to_post", as: "to_post"
    get "/app/views/pages/my_vault.html.erb", to: "pages#my_vault", as: "my_vault"
    get "/app/views/pages/my_settings.html.erb", to: "pages#my_settings", as: "my_settings"
    get "/app/views/pages/contacts.html.erb", to: "pages#contacts", as: "contacts" #THIS ROUTE
  end
  root 'pages#home'
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :circles, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

**controllers/pages_controller.rb:**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the index.html.erb view in views/pages, this is the file that will be rendered by the PagesController index action

Comment: hey James, I don't have an index.html.erb view. The page that I want to render is contacts.html.erb

Should I use ```get "/app/views/pages/contacts.html.erb", to: "pages#index", as: "contacts"``` in my routes instead?

Comment: The output shown in the terminal running your rails server, and therefore your log file will show what controller action is being processed with what parameters if any, just confirm that you see something like `Started get ...` followed by `processing by PagesController#index as HTML`

Comment: The controller action has the responsibility of rendering the view. Rails magic will automatically render a view named after the action in the relevant views folder named after the controller. If you want to render a different view then the index action needs to call the render method `render 'contacts'`

Comment: You are working against Rails and therefore not being able to take advantage of Rails functionality automatically but this is more than that. an index.html file is standard in any folder of any web application not just railsso tyour paths in your urls will make more sense

Comment: Started GET "/app/views/pages/contacts.html.erb" - this is exactly as desired.

Processing by PagesController#contacts as HTML - not as expected but changed PagesController ```index``` method to ```contacts```? However still not returning

Comment: So.. 
```def contacts
    @users = User.all
end```

Sorry if completely missing your point - only getting a start on rails and trying to catch up

Comment: Sure, I get that. But then how do I go about creating custom views in relation to establishing an index.html file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216347/discussion-between-jamesc-and-james-stirrat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

...
```

rename contacts.html.erb to index.html.erb

index.html.erb

```
<table class='table table-condensed'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render partial: 'contact', collection: @users, as: :user %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```